# Multibit neural XOR network

Tags: neural-network, xor

I'm trying to train an 8-bit neural network to output XOR of its inputs. I'm using ffnet library (http://ffnet.sourceforge.net/). For low number of input bits (up to 4) backpropagation produces expected results. For 8 bits, NN seems to 'converge', meaning that it outputs the same value for any input. I'm using a multilayer NN: inputs, hidden layer, output, plus bias node.

Am I doing something wrong? Does this NN need to be of certain shape, to be able to learn to XOR?

Edit:

This is the code I'm using:

```
def experiment(bits, input, solution, iters):
    conec = mlgraph( (bits, bits, 1) )
    net = ffnet(conec)
    net.randomweights()
    net.train_momentum(input, solution, eta=0.5, momentum=0.0, maxiter=iters)
    net.test(input, solution, iprint=2)
```

I'm using `momentum=0.0` to get pure back-propagation.

This is a part of the results I get:

```
Testing results for 256 testing cases:
OUTPUT 1 (node nr 17):
Targets vs. outputs:
   1      1.000000      0.041238
   2      1.000000      0.041125
   3      1.000000      0.041124
   4      1.000000      0.041129
   5      1.000000      0.041076
   6      1.000000      0.041198
   7      0.000000      0.041121
   8      1.000000      0.041198
```

It goes on like this for every vector (256 values)

Comment: What transfer function are you using for the neurons?

Comment: This is the code I'm using: http://pastebin.com/gGCQqEK8

Comment: Everything seems to be ok.  So by 8 bits you mean you're giving it something like 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 and saying that should output 1?  I would adjust the number of neurons in the hidden layer from 1 to 8 and see if you get better results.  It may be overlearning the data when you have the input and hidden layers the same.  Keep changing different factors, one at at time (for instance, after hidden layer number, I would play with momentum a bit, as you may be falling into a local minimum).

Comment: I got it working for 7 bits, by decreasing eta to 0.1 and increasing number of iterations to 1M :)

Comment: Great! Eta should be the learning rate, right?